# How to uncheck a radio button in struts2 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have the following radio button. After selecting any radio button, I have a button "CLEAR". On clicking this button, the radio button should be unchecked. Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
<s:radio id="isPriTobaccoUsrId" cssClass="hixFieldText" name="testPlanDto.isPriTobaccoUsr" list="#{'Y':'Yes','N':'No'}" />
```

My javascript:

```
$('#isPriTobaccoUsrId').attr('checked',false);
$('#isPriTobaccoUsrId').prop('checked',false);
$('#isPriTobaccoUsrId').buttonset('refresh');
```

I tried these but no luck.

Also tried:

```
$('#isPriTobaccoUsrId').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struts2 `<s:radio>` tag gives unique id-s to each generated radio button. So using `isPriTobaccoUsrId` id is not an option, use class of the element as selector.

```
$('.hixFieldText').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: What do you mean? It is class. Just try it.

Comment: And I have another doubt. I have used file upload field,that is,<s:file>.....How to make that field empty? I tried $('#filetestplanid2').val(null); where filetestplanid2 is the id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#isPriTobaccoUsrId').removeAttr('checked');
```