# Radio button returning old value if previously selected-submitting and now deselected-submitted in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I have issue in Struts2. The scenario is given below:

I have a group of radio buttons (All unselected at first time), then i select one of them and i could get the corresponding value in Action class when submitted the page.

```
<s:radio id="autopayCardId" name="paymentType" list="autopayQualCardMap" /> 
<s:radio id="autopayNewCardId" name="paymentType" list="autopayNewCardMap" />
<s:radio id="bankAutopay" name="paymentType" list="autopayEFTMap" />
<s:radio id="paymentMethodId" name="paymentType"  list="autopayPaymentMethodMap" />
```

JS code:

```
document.getElementById('autopayCardId').checked=false; 
document.getElementById('autopayNewCardId').checked=false;
document.getElementById('bankAutopay').checked=false;
document.getElementById('paymentMethodId').checked=false;
```

Then again come back on same page, i make all radio button unselected through above JavaScript and submit the page. In Action class i am getting previous selected value of radio button instead of validation actionError like "Please select one radio button".

I am stuck here, could someone please help me out.
I will appreciate your help!!!

Thanks

Comment: Your js for unselecting radio buttons doesn't work, obviously. Show your code.

Comment: Take a look at rendered HTML. Do you see elements with those ids?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to uncheck a radio button in struts2 using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167178/how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button-in-struts2-using-javascript)

Comment: @AleksandrM I am able to uncheck radio buttons successfully, but the problem is that i must get **null** value in the corresponding variable of Action class.

Comment: Could anyone please help me..

Comment: Provide more details: rendered HTML, your action code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use Reset method in your Action class for this `paymentType` property.

Please check : http://www.rkcole.com/articles/struts/crudTutorial/step1.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @jasar but here i have various conditions and Reset method is not helpful.